# Node.js event handler infinite loop

Tags: node.js

If I understand node.js correctly, then a single event handler that does not release the cpu (infinite loop for example) can freeze the whole system. Is this correct?

Comment: true - running `while(1);` will lock the process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a while loop block the node event loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824460/why-does-a-while-loop-block-the-node-event-loop)