# react native, initializing variable causes infinite loop, why is this

Tags: react-native

Consider the program below, when it is run in its current form it never displays "here" to the screen however if the fourth line is commented out then it does. it is my understanding that setState is asynchronous however I would imagine that when var is eventually set to true the while loop will end.

To be clear, this is how I understand what is happening:
The component is created, immediately `componentDidMount` is called, then `this.setState({var: true})` is called. This is done asynchronously so the program splits into two "paths", the first continues on to the while loop where it gets stuck, the second changes var from false to true. Once var is changed from false to true the the first path should break out of the while loop and the second path should end because the asynchronous call is complete. However this is not what happens which is what I find confusing.

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {var: false}; // consider removing this line
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({var: true})
        while (this.state.var == false){}
    }

    render(){
        return(<View style={{padding: 30}}><Text>Here</Text></View>)
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: is it working fine when calling on the setState callback?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The while loop is blocking. The state never gets a chance to update itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a while loop block the node event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824460/why-does-a-while-loop-block-the-node-event-loop)

Comment: If you have figured out a solution, please post the answer then, or if any of the given solution is working, please accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is called after an initial `render` call which is called after the `constructor` is called.

Study this [react lifecyle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

In your example the constructor sets initial state (`var: false`), so when `componentDidMount` is finally called `this.state.var == false` evaluates to `false == false` => `true` thus yielding you an infinite loop.  This infinite loop prevents React from actually setting the new state since `setState` is an asynchronous function.  When you comment out the fourth line, then `this.state.var` is actually `undefined`, so `undefined == false` => `false`, no looping.  It's confusing because you have it 100% reversed.

Comment: but why doesn't `this.setState({var: true})` first change var to true?

Comment: Because `setState` is an asynchronous function, so you can't depend on any state values set immediately after the line containing the `setState` call since React controls when it's actually set.  You can, however, use a `setState` callback to use guaranteed values **after** the state was set.  `this.setState({var: true}, () => console.log(this.state.var));` will show the updated state value.

Read up on the [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) lifecycle function.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the asynchronous nature of React's `setState` lifecycle function to specifically address why your code snippet didn't work.