# Closure not updating inside a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, closures

I'm trying to get a closure to return a value that is supposed to be updated once a promise is resolved (or rejected).

The following code works. Initially the internal variable from within the close returns `NONE` as expected.

Then the first `Promise` is launched, and once that is resolved, the internal variable is updated to `FAIL`.

The second `Promise` is a deliberate delay, just so that we can observe the change of the closured variable.

However, once the while loop is added to the equation, by uncommenting that `loop(x)` section, the update is not observable within the while loop.

I would expect to see this:

```
...
9963000000 NONE
9964000000 NONE
9965000000 NONE
9966000000 NONE
9967000000 NONE
9968000000 FAIL
9969000000 FAIL
9970000000 FAIL
9971000000 FAIL
9972000000 FAIL
9973000000 FAIL
9974000000 FAIL
...
```

I know it might be due to the single threaded blocking, but, is there a way to observe a dynamic external variable from within the `while` loop?

```js
let sleep = async (ms) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => setTimeout (resolve, ms));

let task = async (ms) => new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout (function(){
        const error = true;
        let result;
        if(error){
            result = '_NO_';
            reject({'state': false, 'response': result});
        }else{
            result = '_YES_';
            resolve({'state': true, 'response': result});
        }
    }, ms);
});

let loop = async (cb) => {
    let i = 0;
    while(i<10000000000){
        const value = cb.getResponse();
        (function() {
            if(i%1000000==0){ console.log(i, value) };
            i += 1;
        })(i, value);
    }
}

const linkResponse = (function(){
    let response = 'NONE';
    function setResponse(value) {response = value; return response};
    function getResponse() {return response};
    return { 'setResponse': setResponse, 'getResponse': getResponse };
});

const x = linkResponse();
console.log(x.getResponse());

(async () => {
    task(3000)
        .then(function(res){
            console.log('__OK__', res);
            let response = 'SUCCESS';
            x.setResponse(response)
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('error', err);
            let response = 'FAIL';
            x.setResponse(response)
        });

    sleep(6000)
        .then(function(res){
            console.log(x.getResponse())
        });

    //loop(x);
})();
```

Comment: While loops are indeed blocking the thread and nothing will get executed until that loop is done. There is a very good explanation in stack overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34825352/10101082

So it seems like your async function isn't being executed until the while loop is over.

Also, may I ask, while would you use a while loop?

Comment: Yes. It was just a wrong way to test this issue. I have solved the problem using a recursive function call. I just needed to emulate a background task that was NOT a promise and was still taking some time.

Comment: I ended up using a recursive function, but that ended up with a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. At the end, I had the use a Promise based `sleep()` in there to fix the problem. It is not as fast as a `while` loop, but does the job for now. If anyone knows how I can solve this problem without running into the `RangeError` issue, that would be amazing.

Comment: I just need something that will count infinitely and be fast - without the need to `sleep()` - and will still be able to access external changes to states.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for the help. Just as I was suspecting, it is indeed a blocked thread issue. I solved the problem with a recursive function. I just needed to have a long process running in the background and I naively thought that an infinite loop will do the job.

```
let loop2 = function(i, cb) {
    if(i>100000){
        return
    }
    console.log(i, cb.getResponse());
    i += 1;
    sleep(0)
        .then(function(res){
            loop2(i, cb);
        });
}
```

And then calling:

```
loop2(0, x);
```