# Event during a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, events

I have this code:

```
let release = false;
document.querySelector(".class").onmouseup = () => {
    release = true;
}
document.querySelector(".class").onmousedown = (e) => {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        release = false;
        while (!release) {
            console.log("click pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

But when i click, the event onmouseup is not toggled and the loop doesn't stop.
How i can make this is work ?

Comment: Don't use an infinite loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Don't use a while loop for this. You can use something like `setInterval(() => console.log("click pressed")` because while loops are running in the whole process and block others from executing.

Comment: Since the value of release can never change, your code can never exit that loop, regardless of anything else that happens.

Comment: Related, probably [duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+while+loop+with+mouse+event+condition+never+stops): [Why does a while loop block the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34824460/4642212).

Comment: Yes i know, but there is the event onmouseup who in theories have to change the value of the var release, and stop the loop

Comment: @user4642212 related perhaps, but not duplicated. This is javascript. Not node. (might be same language, but the application is completely different)

Comment: @Bruce “Application” is irrelevant. The language is the same, the _environments_ are different: Node vs. browser (or Web, depending on context). Still, the reason and the culprit for this behavior is fundamentally the same, even if event loops are implemented differently in each environment. There’s currently no environment in which such a `while` loop wouldn’t block execution.

Comment: @Binary_Serox What are you trying to do? A color picker is better implemented with a `mousemove` event, not with a loop.

Comment: Please add the solution in the answer space below. Do not edit the body of the question with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
let colorPickerLoop;
document.querySelector(".class").onmouseup = () => {
    clearInterval(colorPickerLoop)
    console.log('click released');
}
document.querySelector(".class").onmousedown = (e) => {
    colorPickerLoop = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("click pressed")
    }, 10)
}
```

It's not best thing to do i think but it's working

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter said : Dont use infinite loops. That will block code execution.

You have almost a working code. Try this :

```js
  let release = false;
  document.querySelector(".class").onmouseup = () => {
    release = true;
    console.log('click released');
  }
  document.querySelector(".class").onmousedown = (e) => {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        release = false;
        console.log("click pressed")
    }
  }
```

If i get your idea, that should be it.

Comment: i have to use a loop to do an action in loop until the click is release

Comment: @Binary_Serox  What exactly do you need to do, while the button is down?, unfortunately you cant use a while loop that blocks the main event loop.

Comment: @Binary_Serox , If you give us more information on what you want to accomplish, we might help better.You might be better off using async functions. (a loop will block execution, and the one in the code is perfect to completely block the browser)